# Appscript: button that time stamps in column when clicked

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Need to create a button on google sheets, when clicked it time stamps in column AA

Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

The following script may help you

this code updates the timestamp in cell AA1 every time it runs

```
function setTimeStamp() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1').getRange('AA1').setValue(new Date())  
}
```

and this code adds a timestamp to the AA column each time it runs

```
function addTimeStamp(){
  let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1')
  sheet.getRange('AA'+(sheet.getRange('AA:AA').getValues().filter(String).length+1)).setValue(new Date())  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function addtstoaa() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const rg = sh.getActiveRange();
  const r = rg.getRow();
  sh.getRange(r,27).setValue(new Date());
}
```